# SQL select rows based on CASE statement

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I would want to get each ID's 'good' value if exists, 'bad' if it doesn't.

If an ID has index='good', want to return that row for the ID.
If an ID ONLY has index='bad', want to get that one.

How would you go about it?

[image]

Comment: You may want to tag the question with a specific database type (MySQL, SQLite, ...?) since the SQL dialect may affect the answer.

Comment: added, I was hoping there is some general solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
with cte as
(
select id, index, value, row_number() over(partition by id order by case when index='good' then 1 else 2 end) as rn
from tablename
)

select id,index, value
from cte where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(good.id, bad.id) AS id, 
    COALESCE(good.index, bad.index) AS index,
    COALESCE(good.value, bad.value) AS value
FROM data AS good
FULL OUTER JOIN data AS bad on good.id=bad.id and good.index='good' and bad.index='bad'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` to check if there is `index = 'good'` for each `id`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE t1.index = 'good'
   OR NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1 
     FROM tablename t2
     WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.index = 'good'
   );
```